# Android Notification Button (AddAction) to make a Toast Message when pressed

Tags: c#, android, notifications, xamarin.android

I want to add an action on a **Button** of a Notification **(Archive)** like when some one clicks on it, it shows a toast message , below is a sample image :

[image]
**This is my `PendingIntent` line of code :**

```cs
var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
```

**This is my Notification Builder code :**

```cs
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
    .SetContentTitle(title)
    .SetStyle(style).SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
    .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "ARCHIVE", contentIntent)
    .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "REPLY", pIntent)
    .SetAutoCancel(true);

//check bellow
builder.SetDefaults((int)(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate));
```

So generally i want to make a button to make a Notification instead of launching an Activity etc.

**Help me on this I am new in Xamarin.android please.**

**EDITED:**

This is my full code, according to the answer you provided to me but I still getting an Exception:

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

            //Show toast here
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello it's me ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                NotificationManager manager_ = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager_.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }

            AlarmReceiver customReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();

            //Create intent for action 1 (TAKE)
            var actionIntent1 = new Intent();
            actionIntent1.SetAction("ARCHIVE");
            var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            //Create intent for action 2 (REPLY)
            var actionIntent2 = new Intent();
            actionIntent2.SetAction("REPLY");
            var pIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            Intent resultIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);
            /*
            var resultIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);*/

            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            // Instantiate the Big Text style:
            Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();

            var builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .SetContentTitle("Diabetics Reminder")
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "REPLY", pIntent1)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "ARCHIVE", pIntent2)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                .SetStyle(new Notification
                    .BigTextStyle()
                    .SetSummaryText("")
                    .SetBigContentTitle(title)
                    .BigText(message))
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

            builder.SetContentIntent(pending);

            var notification = builder.Build();
            //Add intent filters for each action and register them on a broadcast receiver
            var intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.AddAction("ARCHIVE");
            intentFilter.AddAction("REPLY");

            context.RegisterReceiver(customReceiver, intentFilter);

            var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
            manager.Notify(10010, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Error Image :**

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `BroadcastReceiver` to be able to show a `Toast` when you click on the action.
For each action, you need an `Intent` that fires a BroadcastReceiver Intent. Here an example on how it would look like:

**Custom BroadcastReceiver**

```cs
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class CustomActionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Show toast here
        Toast.MakeText(context, intent.Action, ToastLength.Short).Show();

        var extras = intent.Extras;
        if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
        {
            NotificationManager manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
            if (notificationId != -1)
            {
                manager.Cancel(notificationId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Build the Notification**

```cs
var customReceiver = new CustomActionReceiver();

// Create intent for action 1 (ARCHIVE)
var actionIntent1 = new Intent();
actionIntent1.SetAction("ARCHIVE");
var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

// Create intent for action 2 (REPLY)
var actionIntent2 = new Intent();
actionIntent2.SetAction("REPLY");
var pIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);


Intent resultIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);
var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .SetContentIntent(contentIntent).SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
    .SetContentTitle(title)
    .SetStyle(style)
    .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
    .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "ARCHIVE", pIntent1)
    .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "REPLY", pIntent2)
    .SetAutoCancel(true);

builder.SetDefaults((int)(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate));

// Add intent filters for each action and register them on a broadcast receiver
var intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.AddAction("ARCHIVE");
intentFilter.AddAction("REPLY");

context.RegisterReceiver(customReceiver, intentFilter);

var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
```

Comment: I tried to implement your answer @Rendy, but am getting an error , so please check my full code i have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

You cannot register a broadcast receiver intent inside another broadcast receiver. Try this instead:

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

            // Show toast here
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello it's me ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                var manager_ = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager_.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }

            // Create intent for action 1 (ARCHIVE)
            var actionIntent1 = new Intent();
            actionIntent1.SetAction("ARCHIVE");
            var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            // Create intent for action 2 (REPLY)
            var actionIntent2 = new Intent();
            actionIntent2.SetAction("REPLY");
            var pIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            Intent resultIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);
            // var resultIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            // resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);

            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            // Instantiate the Big Text style:
            Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();

            var builder = new Notification.Builder(context).SetContentTitle("Diabetics Reminder")
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "REPLY", pIntent1)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "ARCHIVE", pIntent2)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                .SetStyle(new Notification
                    .BigTextStyle()
                    .SetSummaryText("")
                    .SetBigContentTitle(title)
                    .BigText(message))
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

            builder.SetContentIntent(pending);

            var notification = builder.Build();

            var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
            manager.Notify(10010, notification);
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "ARCHIVE" , "REPLY" })]
    public class CustomActionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // Show toast here
            Toast.MakeText(context, intent.Action, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                var manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Rendy Del Rosario